# History and theology, or just current doctrine?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this place suitable for asking about the history of Christian churches, how they changed over time, and became what they are seen today?

Comment: Reference: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) See types 3 and 4.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, absolutely.

The only caveat I would add is to make sure you ask *specific* questions. Don't throw out questions that would require sweeping generalizations to answer; include details about exactly what doctrines, churches and areas of history you want to learn about — things that can be answered with specific references and details.